# How to create dropdown button inside pop up alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a dropdown button inside my pop up alert. And, the dropdown button must populate from array from the database. Currently, I success create dropdown button (html button) that populate an array from database. But, I have no idea how to take that dropdown button to be inside the pop up alert.

HTML :

```html
<!--Trigger-->
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Choose Stations</button>
<!--Menu-->
<div id="dropdown-station-list" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-secondary">
</div>
<p id="station"></p>
<!--Trigger-->
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Choose Stations</button>
<!--Menu-->
<div id="dropdown-station-list" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-secondary">
</div>
<p id="station"></p>
```

Javascript :

```js
$(function() {
  $.get("{% url 'rt3:api_station_list' %}", function(data) {
    // $("#dropdown-station-list").empty();
    alert("Choose which station you want to start your job")
    for (var i in data) {
      var dropdown_item = $("<button>", {
        class: "dropdown-item",
        text: data[i].name
      }).click(function() {
        var selected_tag = $(this).text();
        console.log(selected_tag + " selected");
        alert("Your location is : " + selected_tag);
        $("#station").append(selected_tag);
        $(this).addClass("active");
      });
      $("#dropdown-station-list").append(dropdown_item);
    }
  });
});
```

I want to create dropdown button inside my alert pop up messages like this ... [look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v2Bb.jpg)

Comment: Put simply: You can't using `alert()` - you have to show and handle your own modal dialog.  Rather than re-invent the wheel, use an existing framework for this (such as jquery-ui or bootstrap) or a more specific module/jquery-addon.

Comment: freedomn-m is right, the browser alert box is not capable of dropdown functionality and a Bootstrap Modal is probably your best/easiest solution. W3 have a fantastic example. Have a quick play around and I'm sure it'll make sense - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for enlighten me. May the force always be with you. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RobJeffrey Thank you for your suggestion. May your life fulls with joy and happiness.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think [Magnific popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) would be perfect for your usage. You can also use form inside magnific popup as shown here [Popup with form](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/). You can customize popup as per your needs like you can have drop-down inside this popup and call it like inline popup.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try it and will do my best. Thanks a lot Jennis Vaishnav. May you always under God's protection.